# Where can I find a good chess database?

Tags: opening, database, online

What is the best chess database out there (quality vs. price). Do you recommend online or offline chess database. Any experience with chessbase, chessok, chesstempo or openingmaster?

Comment: For what purpose and what player strengths should be there?

Comment: What are you planning to use the database for? I assume basic study for my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The TWIC (This Week In Chess) database is your best bet. It's free, has millions of games (many of which are recent and up to date), and is of a high quality.

Here's the link:
http://theweekinchess.com/twic

When you get there, scroll down to the "TWIC Downloads" table and download all the PGN or all the CBV files.

After downloading everything, merge all the games into one database in ChessBase.

Then, you can make this database your reference database (if you don't know how to do this, look up a YouTube tutorial on ChessBase's official channel).

Answer (score 1):

I find that https://365chess.com has an AMAZING range of games - it's the only place I've been able to find some really old games. For basic analysis, I use the https://lichess.org analysis board because the overall experience on the site is so great. Seriously. It's amazing.

Answer (score 0):

openingmaster.com with 26 millions is the biggest chess database with zero duplicates. Smaller 8 mil is OTB and 1,7 mil is Correspondence chess database. All you need is there.